# Sum of adjacent cells for Conway's game of life

Tags: r, conways-game-of-life

I need to sum the adjacent cells for Conway's game of life. 
I have a 20x20 matrix and I need to compute the neighbors in order to apply
the rules of the game.

The first portion of script I have written like this

```
generar_grilla<-function(cant, prob_vida){
  grilla<-matrix(ncol=cant, nrow=cant)
  grilla[i]<-rbinom(cant,1,prob_vida)
  return(grilla)
 }
```

Then I have looked in related posts some rules to compute the neighbors and I found this:

```
vecino<-function(grilla,j,k) {
  cant <- nrow(grilla)
  count <- 0
  if(j > 1) {
    count <- count + grilla[j-1, k]
    if (k > 1) count <- count + grilla[j-1, k-1]
    if (k < cant) count <- count + grilla[j-1, k+1]
  }
  if(j < cant) {
    count <- count + grilla[j+1,k]
    if (k > 1) count <- count + grilla[j+1, k-1]
    if (k < cant) count <- count + grilla[j+1, k+1]
  }
  if(k > 1) count <- count + grilla[j, k-1]
  if(k < cant) count <- count + grilla[j, k+1]
  count
}
```

When I run this part of the script with an example:

```
vecino(grilla,3,5)
```

I get this error:

Error in grilla[j - 1, k] : incorrect number of dimensions

the full script for conway's game can be viewed here: https://www.r-bloggers.com/conway%E2%80%99s-game-of-life-in-r-with-ggplot2-and-animation/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your function `generar_grilla` doesn't make sense. It involves an unspecified `i`. You could write it as follows (note how it is easier to first create the values then shape them into a matrix than it is to first create a matrix and then fill it with values):

```
generar_grilla<-function(cant, prob_vida) {
  cells = rbinom(cant^2,1,prob_vida)
  matrix(cells,nrow = cant)}
```

Then it works as expected:

```
> grilla = generar_grilla(5,.2)
> grilla
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    1    0    1    1
[2,]    0    0    0    0    1
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    1    0    1
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0
> vecino(grilla,2,4)
[1] 3
```